# Add 1 day to original date and put in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I add one day from Created_Date and put into Due_Date field?

It is the smalldatetime data type if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function.

```
UPDATE someTable SET Due_Date = DATEADD(day,1,Created_Date) WHERE ...
```

Comment: thanks you.  would taking a day away then be DATEADD(day,-1,Created_Date)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with respect to DAY, you can just add/subtract directly.  I.e. (borrowing from @David):

```
UPDATE someTable SET Due_Date = Due_Date + 1 WHERE ...
```

It's just a short-cut for DATEADD().